# Has anyone tried to write a shell that fixes errexit (`set -e`)?

Tags: shell-script, error-handling

errexit (`set -e`) is often suggested as a way to make simple scripts more robust.  However, it is generally regarded as a horrible trap by anyone who has seen how it behaves in more complex scripts, in particular with functions.  And a very similar problem can be seen with subshells.  Take the following example, adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926013/exit-subshell-on-error

```
(
set -o errexit
false
true
) && echo "OK" || echo "FAILED";
```

The trap here is that shells show "OK", and not "FAILED".[*]

While the behaviour of `set -e` in specific cases has historically varied in unfortunate ways, shells available on a modern distribution claim to follow the POSIX shell standard, and testing showed the same behaviour ("OK") for all of the following:

- `bash-4.4.19-2.fc28.x86_64` (Fedora)
- `busybox-1.26.2-3.fc27.x86_64` (Fedora)
- `dash 0.5.8-2.4` (Debian 9)
- `zsh 5.3.1-4+b2` (Debian 9)
- `posh 0.12.6+b1` (Debian 9)
- `ksh 93u+20120801-3.1` (Debian 9).

### Question

1. Is there any technical reason why you can't write a shell with similar features to POSIX `sh`, except that it prints `FAILED` for the above code?

   I hope that it would also change `set -e` so that top-level `&&` expressions which return false are considered fatal.  https://serverfault.com/a/847016/133475  And hopefully it would have some nicer idiom to use with grep.

   ```
   set -e

   # print matching lines, but it's not an error if there are no matches in the file
   (
   set +e
   grep pattern file.txt
   RET=$?
   [[ $RET == 0 || $RET == 1 ]] || exit $RET
   )
   ```

   I guess I also assume arithmetic statements (`let` builtin) would be redefined in some way that avoids implicitly coercing their numeric value to a true/false exit status.
2. Is there an example of a shell which does any of this?

   I don't mind looking at something with a different syntax from Bourne. I'm interested in something which is compact, when writing short "glue" scripts, but which also has a compact strategy for detecting errors.  I don't like using `&&` as a statement separator, if it means accidentally omitting a statement separator will cause errors to be silently ignored.

---

[*] EDIT.  This is perhaps not a perfect example to use.  Discussion suggests that a better example would be to move the `set -o errexit` above the subshell.

AFAICT this is very similar to the test case `(false; echo foo) || echo bar; echo \  $?` from the table [here](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/), which says that it would show "foo" (and then "0") on the original Bourne shell and most of its descendents.  The exceptions are "hist.ash" and bash 1.14.7.

When you add `set -e` inside the subshell - `(set -e; false; echo foo) || echo bar; echo \ $?` - there are two additional exceptions, "SVR4 sh sun5.10" and dash-0.3.4.

For the spirit of my question, I suppose having `set -e` inside the subshell was a distraction.  My main interest is in an idiom where you use `set -e` at the top of the script, and it also applies to subshells (which is already the POSIX behaviour).

Jörg Schilling suggests that the Bourne shell from original Unix would print "FAILED" for the example I used in this question, that he has ported this shell to POSIX as ["osh" in schilytools](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html), and that this result has been verified as of release 2018-06-11.  Perhaps this is based on 1) `set -e` being inside the subshell and 2) "SVR4 sh sun5.10".  "osh" is "based on the OpenSolaris sources and thus based on SVR4 and SVID3".  Or perhaps there is some horrifying additional variance caused by adding `&& echo "OK"` in between the subshell and `|| echo "FAILED"`.

I don't think the schily shell answers my question.  You could use subshells for functions (use `(` in place of `{` to run the function in a subshell), and start every subshell with `set -e`.  However, using subshells introduces the limitation that you cannot modify global variables.  At least, I have yet to see anyone defend this as a general purpose coding style.

Comment: My interpretation of the POSIX standard is that the first script should print `FAILED`. ksh93 however prints `OK`.

Comment: @schily based on my reading of stackexchange posts, I think you would be in the minority there :).  I've edited to include tested versions of bash and busybox.  `ksh93` doesn't _look_ like a specific individual version to my modern ears.  I'm interested in any indications for specific shell versions, whether explicitly bourne-compatible or not, it would be relevant background to the question in my mind.

Comment: An impression from the gut does not help here and opinions from others don't do as well. You would need to reason your statements. I would not take `bash` as an example here since all versions of bash including bash-3.x handled `set -e` completely wrong. It took me and David Korn two months to convince the bash maintainer to delay bash-4.0 and to fix it before. Bash was not usable by`make` that calls `sh -ce cmd`. At the same time, we tried to make the POSIX standard text more obvious. As a rule of thumb: POSIX does not make historic UNIX programs wrong unless there is a really good reason.

Comment: @schily Regarding reasoning, I agree with the answer by Fólkvangr, which is backed by an (apparent) POSIX quote. I have updated to include a specific version of `ksh`.

Comment: Do you have a shell in mind which follows your interpretation? Are you implying that Schily `osh` or `bosh` do so? Can you specify the version(s) you tested, for reference?

Comment: I would not call this a gut opinion. Rather, it was based on multiple comprehensive sources explaining common issues encountered when trying to use `set -e`. If you can contradict them, that would make for a very interesting answer to post on this site.

Comment: The way I read the quotation from the POSIX standard from the answer in question, it supports my interpretation and this is also how the historic Bourne Shell behaves. The `osh` variant is a fully portable version of the Solaris Bourne Shell and `bosh` is a POSIXified version of the Bourne Shell with lots of new features, like e.g. the first fully integrated history editor that I created between 1982 and 1984 for `bsh` another shell from me. All versions of the Bourne Shell behave the same for `set -e`. The only exit code related change is the treating of errors in command substitution.

Comment: Maybe we could get closer if you did explain why you believe that the sub-shell in your first example should not exit after calling  false`.

Comment: @schily you can't say "all versions" because that includes the future :-P.  I would like you to say a specific version number you have tested, so it can be documented here and potentially reproduced.  The specific part of the quote in Fólkvangr's answer is "*The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list* following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, a pipeline beginning with the ! reserved word, *or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last*."

Comment: Since I know that I did not change this behavior, I grant this for all releases including 2018-06-11. Since you mention that `while false; do ...; done` should not exit at `false` this just what the Bourne Shell did since 1978. The problem with your first example is that the  `false` command is placed in a way that it's exit code is not evaluated. This results in an `exit` of the related subshell if `set -e` is in effect for that shell.

Comment: @schily edited. I have fudged my initial statement to 'POSIX shells show "OK"'. My understanding is that you would disagree with this statement, at least without further context. However I think it would be true for "the POSIX shells provided as the default on most systems". I have included a followup which I think acknowledges possible loopholes in the statement.

Comment: I wouldn't call them POSIX shells. There are two shells that passed certification: 1) the ksh88 that was modified by Sun, HP and IBM for compliance. This shell now is in conflict with some modifications in the standard that appeared after 2008. 2) a bash-3.x that was hacked by Apple for passing the tests. This bash e.g. has a corrected `echo` (like the one on Solaris) and it passed the `set -e` tests because these tests did not check for the known bash-3.0 deviations. A similar problem in the POSIX test suite let Mac OS slip through even though it comes with a non-compliant `waitid()`syscall.

Comment: So let us call these shells shells that claim POSIX compliance. If you find a reason why your first test should not print `FAILED` I am happy to check it.

Comment: See also [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Answer (score 5):

The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25) (c.f. **-e**)  is clearer than the Bash manual about the `errexit` shell option.

> When this option is on, when any command fails (for any of the reasons
>   listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or by returning an exit status
>   greater than zero), the shell immediately shall exit, as if by
>   executing the exit special built-in utility with no arguments, with
>   the following exceptions:
>
> 1. The failure of any individual command in a multi-command pipeline
>      shall not cause the shell to exit. Only the failure of the pipeline
>      itself shall be considered.
> 2. The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list
>      following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, a pipeline
>      beginning with the ! reserved word, or any command of an AND-OR list
>      other than the last.
> 3. If the exit status of a compound command other than a subshell
>      command was the result of a failure while -e was being ignored, then
>      -e shall not apply to this command.
>
> This requirement applies to the shell environment and each subshell
>   environment separately. For example, in:
>
> `set -e; (false; echo one) | cat; echo two`
>
> the false command causes the subshell to exit without executing echo
>   one; however, echo two is executed because the exit status of the
>   pipeline (false; echo one) | cat is zero.

Clearly, the sample code is equivalent to the following pseudocode.

```
( LIST; ) && COMMAND || COMMAND
```

The exit status of the *list*  is zero because:

- the `errexit` shell option is ignored.
- the return status is the exit status of the last command
  specified in the *list*, here `true`.

Therefore, the second part of the AND list is executed: `echo "OK"`.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the question 'Has anyone tried to write ...', but some thoughts on how it could be done. Curious if anybody can provide feedback.

The common approach in current scripting solutions (Python, JavaScript, and the older Perl, and similar) is to use try ... catch blocks. The expected behaviour is for any error to trigger an exception. This behaviour is in conflict with the *sh behaviour that error are captured in the $?. Clearly the '-e' failed to get it right in such a way that it will work as most developers expects. No need to elaborate here, as this is already documented extensively.

Two possible approach:

- Create a better `set -e`: e.g. `set -ocatcherr` with better error handling.
- Add a new `try { list ; }` command, following modern script solutions

The '-ofailerr` can be defined as follow:

- If any command fails outside control flow (if/while/until), the current executing context should return 1(or exit if this is the top level block). This change will effectively force the developer provide error handling on any command that fail, or explicitly marked command with errors that can be ignored.
- Works for simple scripts, effectively, abort on unhandled error.

The `try { list ; }` approach is similar, just different syntax

Example:

```
function foo {
    cat $* > a.txt
    wc -l a.txt
}

set -oerrfail
foo /non/existing/file    # Will  fail, without executing the "wc -l"

if foo /non/existing/file ; then
   ...
else
   # This is the "catch" block
fi
```

With a try block:

```
try {
    foo /non/existing/file
    ...
} || { catch-block }
```

Effectively, the try is equivalent to "set -oerrofail", running the command list under an 'if ! { ... } ; then { catch-block }